# Java JNI java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError using GetaSyncKeyState in a DLL

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My problem is as follows. I am fairly newby about C/C++ code I have a feeling I am using something incorrectly or not using something that needs to be there. Although I made a test application to see if the dll code executes and it does. I have googled a lot on this and can't seem to find anything on it. If I need to explain anything more please let me know. This is my first post BTW I use this site all the time though it is great.

Java Code returns error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ghostclickerredux.GlobbyMouse.whatButton()I
```

All the below code is in java and is contained in a class that implements the runnable interface. The thread starts and will do the loop as long as... you get the rest. If I am to comment the gM.whatButton() line everything works as normal.

```
boolean recording = true;
do {
    if(xT != gM.getMouseX() || yT != gM.getMouseY()){
        xT = gM.getMouseX(); // This Works.
        yT = gM.getMouseY(); // This Works.
        System.out.println("Mouse X: " + xT + " Y: " + yT); // This Works.
        System.out.println(gM.whatButton()); // This throws me the error.
    }
} while (recording);
```

Below is the javah created header file.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse */

#ifndef _Included_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse
#define _Included_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse
 * Method:    getMouseX
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_getMouseX
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse
 * Method:    getMouseY
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_getMouseY
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse
 * Method:    whatButton
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_whatButton
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Finally the CPP code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include "GlobbyMouse.h"

using namespace std;

int mouseX = 0;
int mouseY = 0;
POINT p;

void setMousePos() {
    if (GetCursorPos(&p)) {
        mouseX = p.x;
        mouseY = p.y;
    } else {
        cout << "Could not set mouse variables..." << endl;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_whatButton
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000) {
        return 0;
    } else
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MBUTTON) & 0x8000) {
        return 1;
    } else
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x8000) {
        return 2;
    } else
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) & 0x8000) {
        return 3;
    } else
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2) & 0x8000) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_getMouseX
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    setMousePos();
    return mouseX;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ghostclickerredux_GlobbyMouse_getMouseY
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    setMousePos();
    return mouseY;
}
```

Comment: How are you building the DLL? Which compiler/linker, and with which command line?

Comment: I'm not an expert in JNI, but I had similar UnsatisfiedLinkError recently. I've resolved it by compiling using gcc within MinGW instead of Cygwin. It's in case you use gcc and Cygwin.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit version of MinGW because I am compiling from a 64 bit computer. Java is also compiling from 64 bit JDK.I'm not sure what you mean by linker but I have MinGW including everything it needs from JDK includes folders. Oh it is using G++ to compile it too.

Comment: @McSprinkles How are you calling the compiler and linker? I had a similar issue recently with MingW64 - for a 32 bit build, I had to use a def file to map the function names, which did not work with MingW64, and I had to use slightly different linker options

Comment: As far as I understood the question of Andreas, what do you write after "g++" in console? What options did you specify after -Wl?

Comment: @Andreas I am using Netbeans which when I build it says it is using
'g++.exe    -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/include -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp'
Using that command above then I guess to make the DLL it uses...
'g++.exe     -shared -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libMouseHooker.dll build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o'

Comment: Your source code is working for me. See https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/GlobbyMouse - you can pull the project through git. The native subdirectory contains a Makefile which builds MouseHooker.dll, and GlobbyMouse.java contains a simple test which calls all three native methods. Maybe you can use this as a starting point - keep an eye especially on the compiler and linker options used in the Makefile.

Comment: I have same problem whenever I add free() or delete[] into JNI code. malloc or new[] does not give any problem.

Comment: @Andreas Your a genius. I had to modify the make file a little. But it works no problem. I am guessing when I built this dll from NetBeans I did not have the right MinGW commands because that seemed to be the only difference... Anyways thank you very much I can finally make this program work haha.